# JQuery Dialog customization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

How can I change the appearance of [jQuery dialog box](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) to a tooltip bubble? Does jQuery dialog supports this kind of customizations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for this option:
http://www.queness.com/post/1696/create-a-beautiful-looking-custom-dialog-box-with-jquery-and-css3

It has a nice tutorial and a demonstration here:
http://www.queness.com/resources/html/project/index.html

Comment: The tutorial mentioned is not related to jQuery UI Dialog.

Comment: Does it HAVE to be jQuery-UI? Seems like overkill?

Comment: That was original question, if you haven't noticed.